# Error while creating virtual environment in Python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, virtualenv

`virtualenv myvirtualenv`

I am new to the virtual environment in Python. I was following this tutorial https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/

But got stuck in step 3

The Error I got:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 58, in _install
    installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 46, in install
    for name, module in self._console_scripts.items():
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 116, in _console_scripts
    entry_points = self._dist_info / "entry_points.txt"
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 103, in _dist_info
    raise RuntimeError(msg)  # pragma: no cover
RuntimeError: no .dist-info at C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.8\image\1\CopyPipInstall\setuptools-50.3.1-py3-none-any, has distutils-precedence.pth, easy_install.py, pkg_resources, setuptools, _distutils_hack

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 58, in _install
    installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 46, in install
    for name, module in self._console_scripts.items():
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 116, in _console_scripts
    entry_points = self._dist_info / "entry_points.txt"
  File "c:\users\vivek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 103, in _dist_info
    raise RuntimeError(msg)  # pragma: no cover
RuntimeError: no .dist-info at C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.8\image\1\CopyPipInstall\pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any, has pip```

Thanks in advance
````

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use `virtualenv` package in python 3.3 or above. There is a built in solution in these versions.
Just run the following command:
`python -m venv myvirtualenv`
It will create a new virtualenv named "myvirtualenv".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following-

```
virtualenv -p python3 myvirtualenv
```